# jQuery script not working in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following script, which is in an external file called at the top of my HTML page. The idea is that I have an Ajax request pinging a database, when the database is updated, the Ajax sees this and calls the function below. It works great in Firefox, but doesn't work at all in IE. Any suggestions?

```
var GoPopUp = function(){
  $('#PopNewCall').fadeIn('slow');
  PageRefreshTimer();
}

//Function which refreshes page after a certain number of seconds with no user Inputs
var PageRefreshTimer = function(){
  setTimeout("location.reload(true);",30000); //1,000 = 1 second
}

//Function which refreshes page after user has clicked refresh
var RefreshNow = function(){
  setTimeout("location.reload(true);",0);
}
```

EDIT: In case anyone is curious, I'm using straight javascript for the ajax. Here it is below. I call it on page load, and then it keeps calling itself in a loop.

```
function checkRefresh(str)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
 else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    if (document.getElementById("lastCallID").innerHTML < xmlhttp.responseText)
    {
        setTimeout(GoPopUp(), 100); 
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout('checkRefresh()',15000)
    }

  }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","getnewid.php",true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { location.reload(true); }, 0);` instead of `setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 0);`

Comment: Also, terminate the variable statements with semi-colons.

Comment: I need to see more of your code: how is the `XMLHttpRequest` instantiated?

Comment: You're using $.ajax, $.get, $.post, or any of the other jQuery AJAX request functions, right?

Comment: For the ajax request? No I'm using straight JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an answer but you should replace

```
        setTimeout("location.reload(true);",0);
```

with

```
setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(true) }, 0);
```

As the former is slow and causes extra-evaluation to take place.

EDIT #2: Change `GoPopUp()` to `GoPopUp`, you might not want to execute it immediately. Same with `checkRefresh`.

```
if (document.getElementById("lastCallID").innerHTML < xmlhttp.responseText)
    {
        setTimeout(GoPopUp, 100); 
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout(checkRefresh,15000)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(true) }, 0);
```

you should write:

```
location.reload(true);
```